# Strings in nested lists

Tags: python, date, nested-lists

I have a list looking like this:

```
record1 = [["2020/02/19", 7.0], ["2020/02/20", 7.3], ["2020/02/21", 6.1]]
```

but I want to change the dates from `yyyy/mm/dd` to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

```
record1= [["19/02/2020", 7.0], ["20/02/2020", 7,3], ["21/02/2020", 6.1]
```

How can I do this?

I cannot just use `::-1` because then everything gets mixed up.

Comment: You could `.split('/')` swap positions and join

Comment: @jvx8ss - Please no.  The `datetime` module should always be used to transform datetimes, due to its mature and robust nature, and the complexity to dates and times.

Comment: @S3DEV If all input are assured to be formatted the same way, isn't using datetime a bit overkill?

Comment: @jvx8ss I'd bet that string manipulations are more costly than converting to datetime and back to string. But I might be wrong, need to test that

Comment: @jvx8ss - Fair statement, but an uncontrollable assumption: “all input are assured to be formatted the same way”.  Overkill? No, in view of addressing (eliminating?) assumptions.

Comment: @jvx8ss Well, I'd lose the bet :) Will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way of doing it using `datetime` module:

```
record1 = [[datetime.strptime(d, '%Y/%m/%d').strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), v] for d, v in record1]
```

This converts it to `datetime` object, then formats it the way you intended

```
>>> record1
[['19/02/2020', 7.0], ['20/02/2020', 7.3], ['21/02/2020', 6.1]]
```

This would be a robust, explicit solution.

But... Some experiments showed that manipulating strings with `split` would be a faster solution:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time


def convert_with_datetime(record1):
    return [[datetime.strptime(d, '%Y/%m/%d').strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), v] for d, v in record1]

def convert_with_split(record1):
    return [['/'.join(d.split('/')[::-1]), v] for d, v in record1]

record1 = [["2020/02/19", 7.0], ["2020/02/20", 7.3], ["2020/02/21", 6.1]] * 10**6



start = time.time()
convert_with_datetime(record1)
end = time.time()
print('convert_with_datetime:', end - start)

start = time.time()
convert_with_split(record1)
end = time.time()
print('convert_with_split:', end - start)
```

The result is:

```
convert_with_datetime: 12.311486959457397
convert_with_split: 1.3060288429260254
```